# AlertDialog - setTitle okay, setMessage okay, both error

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

from my activity I start a first alertDialog with a textView on it, to get a name from the user.
After that the second alertDialog is opened. It has a listView in it and the user has to pick one of its item 2,3 or 4.

For both alertDialogs I want to set a title and a message. But it seems that I only can set one of these. If I try to set both my listView on the second alertDialog stays empty.

Here is my code:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this );

        builder.setTitle("Amount of answers");
       // builder.setMessage("Please choose the amount of answers for your question.");
        ArrayList<Integer> myArrayList= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(Integer i=2;i<=4;i++){
            myArrayList.add(i);
        }
        ListAdapter myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(getBaseContext(), R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,myArrayList);
        builder.setAdapter(myAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if(which==0){
                    startView.amountOfAnswers = 2;
                }
                if(which==1){
                    startView.amountOfAnswers = 3;
                }
                if(which==2){
                    startView.amountOfAnswers = 4;
                }
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),editQuestion.class);
                Bundle myBundle = new Bundle();
                myBundle.putString("fill","false");
                myIntent.putExtras(myBundle);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });


        alert.setTitle("Name of question");
        //alert.setMessage("Please enter the name of your question.");
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        alert.setView(input);
       alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                Editable value = input.getText();
                startView.questionName=value.toString();
                startView.questionPath=startView.quizPath + "/" + startView.questionName;
                builder.show();
            }
        });
       alert.show();
```

When I remove the // before the setMessage methods, my listView is empty.

Do you see my mistake?

Comment: please show the logcat output...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot call setMessage and setAdapter on the Same alert AlertDialog.Builder these both change the content area of the dialog.

> public AlertDialog.Builder setAdapter (ListAdapter adapter, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener)
>
> Added in API level 1
> Set a list of items, which are supplied by the given ListAdapter, to be displayed in the dialog as the **content**, you will be notified of the selected item via the supplied listener.

This is why your list is empty when you call `setMessage`

So what you need to do is create a layout for the second dialog that has a TextView and a ListView in it and set this as the AlertDialog.Builder's View using

> public AlertDialog.Builder setView (View view)

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know that setAdapter and setMessage are exclusiv.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried like this. It's a working code with both title and message

```
private AlertDialog.Builder build;
build = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity.this);
        build.setTitle("Delete");
        build.setMessage("Do you want to delete ?");
        build.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
            }
        });

            build.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
            AlertDialog alert = build.create();
            alert.show();
            return true;
        }
```

Hope it helps ...